# Set Html script position in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to move a external script to a section of my page, but i cant access to css attributes of the item.
It display as a iFrame, and as i read it is difficult to change the style if i don't have direct access to the build of the component.

I am using React-Helmet to import the script.

So, i want to ask. Is there a way to wrap this component into a div?, so i can move the div into the position i want.

[This is my front (I want the play button to be in the menu above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyrcK.png)

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItJ2U.png)

So, the script display outside the div ("radio-player").

[Here is the html structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8JrF.png)

I only need to move the play button to the menu, if there is other way that works, happy to recieve.
Thanks

Comment: Have you read about React Portals?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, because of it i get to the answer. It was a fixed widget, so i set a new id component in the index.html file. From there i didnt need to work with Helmet, and can wrap it in a div component.

Comment: Consider upvoting my comment tem xD

Comment: What does "moving a script" mean? Properly loaded modern scripts run independently of where in the DOM their `<script>` node is encountered (unless they are late-loaded via `<head>` injection, in which case there is only one place they can go).

Comment: Also, if a comment solves the problem, either that comment should be an answer, or the question should be deleted, because a question that gets resolved without an answer is not what Stackoverflow is about ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did set the script on the index.html file on the react project, where you can wrap it into a div and changes its attributes with css from there without problem.